# how to construct a dynamic LINQ to Entities ORDER BY clause?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, dynamic-programming, asp.net-web-api

I know how to construct the WHERE clause, but for some reason I'm not able to construct the order by clause.

```
IQueryable<ShowList> query = from s in db.ShowList select s;

if (title != null)
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.Title == title);
}
```

Here's where things aren't right. I give the user the option to select the column they want sorted and whether he/she wants it DESC or ASC. I think I'm doing something wrong inside the OrderBy ().

The "orderBy" variable is an input from the user and the "order" variable is also an input from from the user.

"orderBy" should be the column name and "order" will be "desc" or "asc"

```
if (orderBy != null && order != null)
            {
                switch (order)
                {
                    case "asc":
                        query = query.OrderBy(s => orderBy);
                        break;
                    case "desc":
                        query = query.OrderByDescending(s => orderBy);
                        break;
                    default:
                        query = query.OrderBy(s => orderBy);
                        break;
                }
            }

return query.ToList();
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argument of `OrderBy` method gives LINQ the key that should be used to order results of the query. So basically what you are currently doing is saying that for all entities string contained in `orderBy` should be used as a key. Therefore no real ordering is performed.

However most likely `orderBy` specifies the name of the property that should be used for ordering. If you do not want/need to make it too complicated, you can go with yet another switch/case:

```
Func<ShowList, Object> orderByFunc = null;
switch (orderBy)
{
    case "Property1":
        orderByFunc = sl => sl.Property1;
        break;
    case "Property2":
        orderByFunc = sl => sl.Property2;
        break;
    // so on
    default:
        orderByFunc = sl => sl.Property1;
        break;
}
```

And then, when actually applying ordering:

```
case "asc":
    query = query.OrderBy(orderByFunc).AsQueryable();
    break;
case "desc":
    query = query.OrderByDescending(orderByFunc).AsQueryable();
    break;
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<TVData.Models.ShowList>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TVData.Models.ShowList>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.OrderBy` and `.OrderByDescending` incorrectly. The lambda expression used in these should produce a value for each item. Instead, you are producing the same value (whatever's in `orderBy`) for each item. You need to do something like this:

```
Func<ItemType, object> orderByExpression;
switch (orderBy)
{
    case "Column1":
        orderByExpression = s => s.Column1;
        break;
    case "Column2":
        orderByExpression = s => s.Column2;
        break;
    ...
    default:
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}

switch (order)
{
    case "asc":
        query = query.OrderBy(orderByExpression);
        break;
    case "desc":
        query = query.OrderByDescending(orderByExpression);
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<TVData.Models.ShowList>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TVData.Models.ShowList>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You get that on the `query = query.OrderBy()` and `query = query.OrderByDescending()` lines? Then you'll also get that with your original code.

Comment: Just change your declaration `IQueryable<ShowList> query` to `var query` or `IEnumerable<ShowList> query`